Hair & Particles shooting in one direction until frame 100?
I'm adding some fur to an insect and sometimes the fur spazzes out and points directly in the +X direction. After some experimenting I found that frame 100 it returns to normal. This is even true with particles. Now the easy solution is to start at frame 100 but I would like to know what to do when it's not possible. I ran into this problem once before and had to just copy the object into a new unaffected file (until that one broke as well.) There are no force fields or keyframes in the file. I changed the tracking axis to all of the choices and it was unaffected. There's no children and hair dynamics checked or unchecked does nothing.



It seems like I fixed it temporarily while taking photos for this post. I added a particle system to the wrong part accidently and now its acting like it's supposed to for now. I still want answers. Is this just a bug I'll have to deal with?

Pleae add your images directly into your question. If you use an external site they won't remain there for future users looking at your question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post
